# Can't seem to get CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to behave in PHP

Tags: php, curl

Ultimately, I'm trying to set up a simple site with links that initiate a cURL POST using basic auth. The href of the link points to `blah.php?dothething`.

In the php file, I have

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'dothething') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://blah/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "thing=1&do=true");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PIPEWAIT, TRUE); //POST takes about 10 sec to process
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERIFYPEER, FALSE); //self-signed cert
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

When I visit the link, I get:

**Warning**:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in **blah.php** on line **31**
**Warning**:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in **blah.php** on line **32**

I've tried `TRUE`, `true`, `"true"`, and `1`, and have gotten the same error every time.

I'm running this on PHP v7.0.14 on DreamHost. Looks like these options have been available since v7.0.7, are they maybe just not available in DreamHost's PHP? If that's the case, is there any way to not validate the cert, other than running it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an underscore:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

Or even better, just go to https://letsencrypt.org/ and get yourself a real cert for free.

Comment: Oh god, I'm an idiot, thanks. Any thoughts on `CURLOPTS_PIPEWAIT`? Not even sure this'll do what I want. The POST takes about 10 seconds to return, and I'd like the page render to hang, but it's not a deal-breaker.

Also, the target is an appliance that I can't easily install a real cert on. Hey, at least it's encrypted.

Comment: No idea on the CURLOPTS_PIPEWAIT, I've never used it.

Comment: Heh and the funny thing is, you had the correct spelling in your post title. :)